# Dados de um Array

Tags: angularjs, array, funções

estou com um probleminha meio complicado aqui, a lógica que devo usar para este tipo de procedimento é um pouco complicada.

Bom, é o seguinte:

**Tenho um array com os seguintes dados:**

```
var dados = [
    {'id':1,'nome':'dom','horario1':'01:00','horario2':'02:00'},
    {'id':1,'nome':'seg','horario1':'07:00','horario2':'08:00'},
    {'id':1,'nome':'ter','horario1':'09:00','horario2':'10:00'},
    {'id':1,'nome':'qua','horario1':'01:00','horario2':'02:00'},
]
```

quero fazer com que o array seja percorrido e todos os que tiverem o mesmo horário ele junte o nome, no exemplo acima ficaria assim:

```
var Retorno = [
    {'id':1,'nome':'dom,qua','horario1':'01:00','horario2':'02:00'},
    {'id':1,'nome':'seg','horario1':'07:00','horario2':'08:00'},
    {'id':1,'nome':'ter','horario1':'09:00','horario2':'10:00'},
]
```

tem como vocês me ajudarem por gentileza, estou apanhando feio aqui!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, consegui resolver desta forma: Crio um array onde o indice são os horários e vejo se já esta setado, se estiver eu concateno o dia, senão eu crio a posição no array.

```
var retorno = [];

for(var dado in dados){
   var index = dados[dado].horario1+"-"+dados[dado].horario2;
   if(retorno[index]){
       retorno[index].nome = retorno[index].nome+","+dados[dado].nome;  
   }else{
       retorno[index] = dados[dado];
   }
}
console.log(retorno);
```

Comment: cara obrigado, eu consegui resolver de outra forma mas não muito diferente, precisou um pouco mais de linhas do código mas funcionou da mesma forma, para o meu sistema no caso

Comment: a minha resposta ta ai acima, mas mesmo assim vou marcar a sua como a que resolveu o problema obrigado amigo

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa seria criar um filtro pra exibir apenas valores únicos. Ex:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('unique', function() {
   return function(colecao, campo) {
      var saida = [], 
          keys = [];

      angular.forEach(colecao, function(item) {
          var key = item[campo];
          if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key);
              saida.push(item);
          }
      });

      return saida;
   };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.dados = [
     {'id':1,'nome':'dom','horario1':'01:00','horario2':'02:00'},
     {'id':1,'nome':'seg','horario1':'07:00','horario2':'08:00'},
     {'id':1,'nome':'ter','horario1':'09:00','horario2':'10:00'},
     {'id':1,'nome':'qua','horario1':'01:00','horario2':'02:00'},
  ]
    
    //Trabalhando com o filtro através do controller.
    function init(){
      var unicos = $filter('unique')($scope.dados, 'horario2');
       console.log(unicos)
    }
    init();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <ul ng-repeat="item in dados| unique:'horario2'">
 <li>{{item.nome}} -- {{item.horario1}} -- {{item.horario2}}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Dessa forma você pode trabalhar com o filtro criado direto no Html e também no Controller e assim pode fazer a junção que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.horariosFormatados = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < $scope.horarios.length; x++) {
            var nome = '';
            var existe = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.horarios.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura1 === $scope.horarios[i].horario_abertura1 && $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura2 === $scope.horarios[i].horario_abertura2 && $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura3 === $scope.horarios[i].horario_abertura3 && $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura4 === $scope.horarios[i].horario_abertura4) {
                    if (nome === '') {
                        nome = $scope.horarios[i].horario_dia;
                    } else {
                        nome = nome + ", " + $scope.horarios[i].horario_dia;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($scope.horariosFormatados.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.horariosFormatados.length; i++) {
                    console.log($scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura1 + " " + $scope.horariosFormatados[i].hi1);
                    if ($scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura1 === $scope.horariosFormatados[i].hi1 && $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura2 === $scope.horariosFormatados[i].hf1 && $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura3 === $scope.horariosFormatados[i].hi2 && $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura4 === $scope.horariosFormatados[i].hf2) {
                        console.log(existe);
                        existe = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (existe === false) {
                $scope.horariosFormatados.push({'dias': nome, 'hi1': $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura1, 'hf1': $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura2, 'hi2': $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura3, 'hf2': $scope.horarios[x].horario_abertura4});
            }
            console.log($scope.horariosFormatados);
```